# File Encoding Conversion from ANSI to CP852/IBM852

Tags: vb6

I need to convert files with encoding from ANSI to IBM852/CP852 using VB6 and here is what I have done so far.

```
Sub ConvertEncoding(ByVal InCharSet, ByVal OutCharSet, ByVal strInFileName As String, Optional strOutFileName As String = vbNullString)
    Dim objInputStream, objOutputStream As Object

    If IsCharset(InCharSet) And IsCharset(OutCharSet) Then
        Set objInputStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Set objOutputStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        With objInputStream
            .Open
            .Type = adTypeBinary
            .LoadFromFile strInFileName
            .Type = adTypeText
            .Charset = InCharSet
            intWritePosition = 0
            objOutputStream.Open
            objOutputStream.Charset = OutCharSet
            Do While .EOS <> True
                strText = .ReadText(adReadLine)
                objOutputStream.WriteText strText, adWriteChar
            Loop
            .Close
        End With
        objOutputStream.SaveToFile IIf(strOutFileName = vbNullString, strInFileName, strOutFileName), adSaveCreateOverWrite
        objOutputStream.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above when I execute it was able to convert from PC default to UTF-8, Unicode but when I tried to convert it to IBM852/CP852 it remains at the ANSI encoding.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it, BTW the codes are also from here and just modified it.

Comment: No idea what you expect.  CP862 *is* an ANSI codepage, so there is no telling what you mean or are trying to accomplish.  If you want to go from some other ANSI codepage to 862 the ASCII subset transfers one-to-one but anything from the 80-FF range has no mapping.

Comment: Not to mention the other poor coding practices and errors in the code shown above.  Why late binding?  Why loop line by line to copy data?  You have also lost the "newline" breaks (probably CRLF since you let that default).  Why the goofy `Do While <> True` instead of the cleaner `Do Until`?

Comment: @Bob77: There is no `Do Until` in C# or any curly brackets language *and* `Do While ... Loop`/`Do ... Loop While` is so much more portable construct, even with `Exit Do` thrown in. Probably not a good idea to start learning "bad habits" so late in the game.

Comment: I agree.  Bad habits liike using C# should be avoided.

Comment: So can anyone help me to code the right way and will work to convert a unicode file to ibm852 file encoding? thanks